# How to assigning value to parameter in dynamic query inside cursor

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My problem is in the line with `EXEC`, all works except adding value to `@counter`.

If I execute something like below there is no problem:

```
EXEC('if exists(select * from '+ @table + ' where ' + @column + ' = ' + @someValue + ') print ''test''');
```

What to do to add value to the `@counter`? When I'm running below code I'm getting error:

> Incorrect syntax near 0.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSP
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE testCursor CURSOR;

    DECLARE @table NVARCHAR;
    DECLARE @column NVARCHAR;
    DECLARE @someValue NVARCHAR;
    ...

    BEGIN
        DECLARE testCursor2 CURSOR;
        DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
        ...

        BEGIN
            DECLARE @result INT = 0;

            EXEC( 'if exists(select * from '+ @table + ' where ' + @column + ' = ' + @someValue + ') set ' + @counter + '=1' );

            IF (@counter > 0)
                PRINT 'test';
            ...
        END
    ...
    END
END
go
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSP
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE testCursor CURSOR;

    DECLARE @table NVARCHAR;
    DECLARE @column NVARCHAR;
    DECLARE @someValue NVARCHAR;
    ...

    BEGIN
        DECLARE testCursor2 CURSOR;
        DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
        ...

        BEGIN
            DECLARE @result INT = 0;

            declare @sqlText nvarchar(max)= N'if exists(select * from '+ @table + ' where ' + @column + ' = ' + @someValue + ') SET @counter = 1' 

            DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500) = N'@counter INT OUTPUT'; 

            EXEC sp_executesql @sqlText, @ParmDefinition, @counter = @counter OUTPUT  ;
                if(@counter>0)
                    print 'test';
            ...
        END
    ...
    END
END
```